# Obtener el valor de un Input Text segun ID

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy intentando obtener el valor de un input Text según su Id.

en php estoy imprimiendo de esa forma, Estoy haciendo una consulta. Y según los resultados. voy imprimiendo  con el Foreach.
la cantidad de inputText pasandoles el ID.

```html
<?php

 foreach($resultado as $row){
   $IDcali=$row['IDcali'];
?>

 <input type="text" id="<?php echo$IDcali;?>"  min="0" max="10" name="<?php echo$IDcali;?>" class="form-control" "></th>
                    <th>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-pink" onclick="RegistroCali(<?php echo$IDcali;?>)>Guardar</button>

<?php
}
?>

<script>

function RegistroCali(IDcali){

var calificacion=document.getElementById(IDcali).value;

alert(calificacion);
alert(IDcali);

}
</script>
```

estoy intentando mandar el IDcali a la funcion de JS. para poder Recuperar su valor que se ha introducido en el input text. 
pero no me reconoce. no sé que estoy haciendo mal.
ya que si muestro en el alert. me imprime el valor que esta recibiendo
pero si muestro el de calificacion. dice indefinida.

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error? Intenta pasarle el id entre comillas simples: `onclick="RegistroCali('<?= $IDcali ?>')"`.

Comment: el valor si lo pasa como tal a la funcion, en el alert me lo muestra.
pero cuando le paso esa variable al :

document.getElementById(IDcali).value;

segun el ID. No me lo muestra, Me dice Indefinidia o en dado caso no muestra nada :(

Answer (score -1):

basta con agregar dentro del ciclo lo siguiente:

```
var text = $('#<?php echo $IDcali; ?>').val();
```

no se si trabajaras con onload, onclick, keyup, etc...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<?php echo $IDcali; ?>").keyUp(function(){
            var text = $('#<?php echo $IDcali; ?>').val();
    }); 
});
```

> Puede que tenga algún error de sintaxis.